# Linear layout with textview and button alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying hard time to align this paticular layout but unable to set it correctly.

can anyone help me out with this.

I need exactly the row layout as shown below:

[image]

This is what I have now:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtadd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLongDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_header"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btndelete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtadd"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
```

I want the button to be centered for both the linear layoyuts and the long text should be marquee.
The problem is If I set the long textview to `fill_parent` its pushing the button.

Comment: Just an importent note. When you want to apply a wight property to children views you have to set the height/width to 0dp depending of the layout orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LinearLayout` with `weight` properties :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtadd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLongDesc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_header"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btndelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect..Thanks much and the text is not marqueeing in lollipop..can u say me the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtadd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLongDesc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btndelete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will help you.